# TouchUtils with Android Emulator

Tags: android, unit-testing

Has anyone been able to successfully perform unit testing on the Android Emulator using methods offered by the `TouchUtils` class?

I'm able to get the test(s) to pass on my device but when I run the exact same test(s) (and test suite) on an emulator, any test using a `TouchUtils` methods always throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1327)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1281)
at android.view.IWindowManager$Stub$Proxy.injectPointerEvent(IWindowManager.java:1196)
at android.app.Instrumentation.sendPointerSync(Instrumentation.java:902)
at android.test.TouchUtils.drag(TouchUtils.java:786)
at android.test.TouchUtils.dragViewTo(TouchUtils.java:633)
...
```

I've unlocked the keyguard and even ran other (non TouchUtils) test cases which have passed.

I do not have the `@UiThreadTest` applied nor am I running anything that requires code to run on the UI thread.

When I comment out the line that employs `TouchUtils.dragViewTo(...)` and put in a simple `assert(true)`, the test runs and passes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you found the answer? I'm running with this trouble too and there's not too much to find on the issue.

Answer (score 2):

It happens if your phone is locked or there is some other Activity on the HomeScreen.

Comment: It works on my phone, it doesn't work on the emulator.
I've removed the lock from the screen as I can see other tests being run on the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

The emulator is so slow, that when you emulate a UI interaction after you dismiss the virtual keyboard, there isn't enough time for the virtual keyboard to dismiss and so you are actually injecting events into the virtual keyboard and not your application.

Simply sleep on your thread for about 500-1000ms before you attempt to do any UI interactions after hiding the soft keyboard.

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(500);
} 
catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```